# Dask parallel processing is much slower than using pathos multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, dask, pathos

I am a relative newbie using dask and I was trying to understand how can I leverage dask multiprocessing up and above pathos multiprocessing. To my surprise dask is 3-4 times slower than pathos. I am clearly doing something wrong and would appreciate any guidance on this.

Below is the code where I am trying to set up a trivial arithmetic manipulation:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
import pandas as pd, numpy as np,time
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
nCores = cpu_count()

class test_pathos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.NumCols = 270
        self.NumRows = 250000
        self.cols = ['Col'+ str(i) for i in range(self.NumCols)]
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(self.NumRows,self.NumCols)),columns=self.cols)


    def ProcessCol(self,x):
        colname = x.name
        DQCol = colname + r'_DQ'
        self.data.loc[:, DQCol] = self.data[colname] + 1

    def AddTodata(self,colname):
        DQColumn = colname+r'_DQ'
        self.data.loc[:,DQColumn] = self.data[colname]+1
        return self.data[DQColumn]

    def AddProcess(self):
        p = Pool(nodes = nCores)
        ChangedCols = p.map(self.AddTodata,self.cols)
        ChangedColsDf = pd.concat(ChangedCols,axis=1)
        self.data = pd.concat([self.data,ChangedColsDf],axis=1)

    def AddProcess_apply(self):
        '---self.data.apply(self.ProcessCol)'
        dd.from_pandas(self.data, npartitions=nCores).map_partitions(lambda df : df.apply(self.ProcessCol)).compute(scheduler='processes')


'----------------------------------------------------MAIN---------------------------------------------------------------------'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_obj = test_pathos()
    tinit = time.time()
    shapebeforetransmutation = test_obj.data.shape
    test_obj.AddProcess()
    shapeaftertransmutation = test_obj.data.shape
    print('Pathos call time is :', time.time() - tinit)
    tinit = time.time()
    test_obj.AddProcess_apply()
    print('Dask call time is : ', time.time() - tinit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends on many things.  It could be overheads, data transfers, or anything else.  Unfortunately it's not very easy to tell without actually redoing your experiment.

For more understanding on Dask performance I recommend reading through the docs [Understanding Performance](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html)